# How to determine where pip3 installs binaries/scripts for non-user installs?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I can determine where pip installs package binaries/scripts with `pip3 install --user mypackage` using:

```
$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin
```

Is there a mechanism for determining where **non-user** binaries/scripts get installed (e.g. `pip3 install mypackage`) get installed?

Note that I'm only interested in where the binaries/scripts get installed and NOT where the library code gets installed.

**Update:**

The objective is to ensure that that the PATH environment variable contains the folder where the binaries/scripts get installed as this has caused some issues in the past for me.

**Update 2:**

```
$ python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('scripts'))"
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin

$ python3 -c "from pip._internal.locations import bin_py; print(bin_py)"
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
```

However, pip3 installs into `/usr/local/bin`

Note that:

```
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: import mypackage; mypackage.__ file__

Comment: Thanks @sergey.  I have updated the question to clarify that this approach may not work for me.

Comment: This is surprising behavior, to me. I am not familiar with mac and homebrew though. -- Are you sure that the `pip3` script corresponds to the `python3` binary? Where are binaries/scripts installed when you call `python3 -m pip install Something`? -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: You also might want to check the outputs of `python3 -m site` and `python3 -m sysconfig`?

Answer (score 5):

This has already been answered here (but I can't "close as duplicate", since there is a bounty):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62167797

---

I believe the canonical way (going forward) is to use `sysconfig.get_path(...)`. Depending on what is needed exactly, it is possible to combine *scheme* and *name*. So maybe for your exact use case:

```
import sysconfig

scripts_path = sysconfig.get_path('scripts')
print(scripts_path)
```

As a *one-liner* from the shell:

```
python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('scripts'))"
```

---

Other things that might help identify the correct directory:

```
python -m site
```

```
python -m sysconfig
```

---

***References***:

- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sysconfig.html#using-sysconfig-as-a-script
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/site.html#command-line-interface
- https://discuss.python.org/t/proper-way-to-determine-install-location-of-console-scripts/7188

Answer (score 1):

## `pip`'s Source

`pip`'s source code at `_internal/locations.py` shows how the system bin path is resolved:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/3fe826c699d85eccc7ebf16f4d86c851b2a1e705/src/pip/_internal/locations.py#L63-L91

```py
if WINDOWS:
    bin_py = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Scripts')
    bin_user = os.path.join(user_site, 'Scripts')
    # buildout uses 'bin' on Windows too?
    if not os.path.exists(bin_py):
        bin_py = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin')
        bin_user = os.path.join(user_site, 'bin')
else:
    bin_py = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin')
    bin_user = os.path.join(user_site, 'bin')

    # Forcing to use /usr/local/bin for standard macOS framework installs
    # Also log to ~/Library/Logs/ for use with the Console.app log viewer
    if sys.platform[:6] == 'darwin' and sys.prefix[:16] == '/System/Library/':
        bin_py = '/usr/local/bin'
```

Some additional documentation on `sys.prefix` is available here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix

According to the Git History, this resolution behavior has not been touched since some time in 2017. Trying to trace the usage of this variable does not seem to indicate this variable is exposed using `pip` directly through a command.

---

## A Solution

Since this does not appear to be exposed directly in the CLI, you could import the script to access the resolved bin location:

```
python -c "from pip._internal.locations import bin_py; print(bin_py)"
```

For example:

- On Linux:

  ```
  $ python -c "from pip._internal.locations import bin_py; print(bin_py)"
  /usr/local/bin
  ```

  This appears to match the location of where scripts are installed packages that have a script/bin. E.g.

  - **system-installed**:

  ```
  $ pip install uvicorn >/dev/null && which uvicorn
  /usr/local/bin/uvicorn
  ```

  - **user-installed**:

  ```
  $ pip install --user uvicorn >/dev/null && find "$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
  /root/.local/bin
  /root/.local/bin/uvicorn
  ```
- On Windows:

  ```
  $ python -c "from pip._internal.locations import bin_py; print(bin_py)"
  C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
  ```

This method also works for finding the bin directory of a virtual environment.

Comment: Relying on implementation details and internal APIs is prone to failure in the future.

Comment: @sinroc you can copy the relevant code from pip._internal.locations and make your own script/library.

Comment: @pbacterio Why copy internal private code from _pip_, when the canonical solution (moving forward) is in the standard library already?