# How to make GitHub action runners find an executable installed using `pip install --user`?

Tags: python, macos, pip, github-actions

When using `python3 -m pip install --user foo` on **github action runners**, supposing `foo` package contains an executable `bar`.

I would like to know where the user bin directory is located on *Linux*, *Windows* and *MacOS* runners in order to add it to `GITHUB_PATH`.

So a subsequent call like `command -v bar`, `which bar` or `bar` won't fail...

EDIT:

- On Linux, using bash, it will be:

  ```yaml
  run: echo "$HOME/.local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
  ```
- On Windows, using powershell, it could be:

  ```yaml
  run: echo "$((Get-Item ~).FullName)/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
  ```
- On MacOS, using bash, it will be:

  ```yaml
  run: echo "$HOME/Library/Python/3.9/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
  ```

Comment: On any platform, it's the `bin` directory under `python -m site --user-base`

Comment: @AnonCoward on Windows it's `PythonXY/Scripts` not `bin`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64395497

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62167797

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically determine pip 'user install' location Scripts directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162970/programmatically-determine-pip-user-install-location-scripts-directory)

Answer (score 0):

***Duplicate question***:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62167797

---

I believe the following should give the expected result

```
import os
import sysconfig

user_scripts_path = sysconfig.get_path('scripts', f'{os.name}_user')
print(user_scripts_path)
```

But it might be that *pip* uses a different logic internally (probably based on [*distutils*](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html)), but the results should still be the same.

**References**

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.name